# How to change Text and Styles in Bootstrap UI Paging with AgnularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-ui

I dont get how to change styles and default text here.
Here`s html:

```
 <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
```

Here`s JS:

```
  $scope.totalItems = $scope.data.length;
  $scope.totalItems = $scope.data.length;
  $scope.currentPage = 4;
  $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewby;
  $scope.maxSize = 5;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you provide more details, like what you want to change? or what the actual issue is with the code?

Comment: The issue is default text and default boostrap styles on this pagination tag.I cannot find a proper way to change it:(

Comment: Like it has default blue color and I want it to become red.Same with the text there.

Comment: Use the CSS `ul.pagination li > a {
    color: red !important;
}` Please note the `!important` is to override all the other styles for that element (which was previously blue).

Comment: @Naren Murali ow thanks,it worked! Maybe you also know how to change text?:)

Comment: What do you want the text to be changed to? and which text to change?

Comment: First,Previous,Next,Last that are things I want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing the color you can use the CSS.

**CSS:**

```
ul.pagination li > a { color: red !important; }
```

For changing the text you can use the attributes of UI-Bootstrap.

**HTML:**

```
<pagination first-text="Hello" previous-text="World" next-text="Good" 
 last-text="Day!"  total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
```

<kbd>**Plunkr Demo**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

hi i thinks it healp full your text chnage

```
<script id="template/pagination/pagination.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-class="{active: page.active}">
            <a href data-ng-show="page.text  == 'Previous'" ng-click="selectPage(page.number)"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> </a>
            <a href data-ng-show="page.text >= 1 || page.text == 'First' || page.text == 'Last'" ng-click="selectPage(page.number)">{{page.text}}</a>
            <a href data-ng-show="page.text == 'Next'" ng-click="selectPage(page.number)"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```